# Crash with inserting pair into std::map Cocos2d-x 2.x iOS 5

Tags: c++, ios5, dictionary, cocos2d-x, std

I'm working on game based on Cocos2d-x 2.x.

I create std::map and insert a pair of strings:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> props;
std::string value("1");
std::string key("type");
props.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(key, value));
```

On iOS 6 and 7 it works fine. On iOS 5 it crashes on the `insert` with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6), and debugger highlights last line of code in `iOS 7.1 > usr/include > c++ > 4.2.1 > bits > stl_pair.h`:

```
/** There is also a templated copy ctor for the @c pair class itself.  */
  template<class _U1, class _U2>
    pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p)
: first(__p.first), second(__p.second) { }
};
```

In Cocos2d-x's source code same code works fine, for example in CCFileUtils.cpp (`fullPathForFilename` method).
What do I do wrong?

Comment: On a side note : why do you want to support iOS 5? According to this : https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/ only 2% of devices are using iOS lower than 6, and this number is bound to decrease.

Comment: @Losiowaty it's simple: I have device with iOS 5 and I test app on it.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this issue too. It works fine on iOS 6 and iOS7. And it works fine in debug mode on iOS 5.  It seems related to XCode 5.1 or iOS SDK 7.1.  Our app's previous version (before Xcode 5.1 and iOS SDK 7.1) works fine on iOS 5.

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: Math, I think (i didn't try) using old version of Xcode is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is related to what C/C++ compiler Xcode 5 uses?

Try comparing the `GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD`, `CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD`, `CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY` build settings for your target under Xcode 4/5.